# vim : if filereadable 

Tags: vim

I use this functions for load configuration for particular extension

```
function! LoadSnippets(extension)                                                        
    let file = expand("~/.vim/templates/".a:extension.".snippets.vim")                   
    if filereadable(file)                                                                
        silent! execute 'source '.file                                                   
    endif                                                                                
endfunction  

autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile * silent! call LoadSnippets('%:e')
```

but the `if` never is True. Without the `if`, the function work ok.

why the `filereadable` don't find the file?

#### EDIT

I try with

```
fnamemodify(file,':p')
```

but is the same.

Comment: Have you tried echoing 'file' to see what is being returned by the call to `expand`?  My guess is it's not returning what you're expecting.

Comment: @RandyMorris if out of `if`, I put `execute 'sp ' filename` vim open filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the autocommand you are passing the *string* `'%:e'` to your function. Then, in the first line of your function this string is concatenated to form `"~/.vim/templates/%:e.snippets.vim"`.

At this point `%` and `:e` do not have any special meaning to Vim. They are not expanded by `expand()` and the resulting path will never point to a readable file.

Passing `'%:e'` directly to `expand()` will work though, and this would fix it:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile * silent! call LoadSnippets(expand('%:e'))
```

Comment: In the function, I change to `expand("~/.vim/templates/"). expand(a:extension) .".snippets.vim"`. `expand(a:extension)` fix the problem